# Как вернуть 200 статус после получения POST запроса? (Flask, Python)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, apache, flask, webhook

Установлено и работает: apache2 + flask + SSL от Let's encrypt для домена 2 уровня

`/tgwh` - url вебхука от телеграма

Сообщения приходят, но flask возвращает 500 статус и телеграмм каждую минуту пытается отправить заново.
Минимально код выглядит так:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
 SECRET_KEY = 'secret'
 app = Flask(__name__)
 app.config['TESTING'] = False
 app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True


@app.route('/tgwh', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def webhook():
if request.method == 'POST':
       data = request.get_json(force=False, silent=False, cache=True)
       detect_type_of_message(data)
    return jsonify(result={"status": 200})

 if __name__ == "__main__":
     app.run(debug=False)
```

Вопрос: как вернуть 200 ответ после получения POST запроса?  Что я делаю не так?
Сейчас - 500й(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

500 ответ  - это внутренняя ошибка сервера. Соответсвтенно что-то ломается коде. На первый взляд:

- Отступы внутри `if request.method == 'POST':`
- Отсутствует декларация/импорт `detect_type_of_message` (я не помню такой внутренней функции Flask
- Отсутствует импорт `from flask import jsonify`
- Проверь все отступы, так как в приведенном коде - есть лишние пробелы в том числе перед `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: Отступы - в коде в порядке, иначе бы ругался питон, но проверил ещё раз. detect_type_of_message - это моя функция объявлена ниже для обработки POST данных . И from flask import jsonify - за это спасибо, действительно не было.  Откатил на старую версию git - скорее всего манипуляции с функцией detect_type_of_message